# How to open window.xaml file on context menu of excel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, office-interop

I want to open a new window on context menu(right click) of Excel.

For this I opened an Excel file, and added a `Go to Link` menu on right click, but when I click on this menu it does not open a Window and gives the error message `"STA thread attribute must be defined"`.

Below is the code.

```
Excel.Application _Excel = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Worksheet WS = new Excel.Worksheet(); 
Excel.Workbook WB;

Object defaultArg = Type.Missing;

try
 {
    _Excel.Visible = true;

    CommandBar cellbar = _Excel.CommandBars["Cell"];
    CommandBarButton button =(CommandBarButton)cellbar.FindControl(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 0, "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    if (button == null)
    {
       // add the button
       button = (CommandBarButton)cellbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, cellbar.Controls.Count, true);
       button.Caption = "Go to Link";
       button.BeginGroup = true;
       button.Tag = "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU";
       button.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(MyButton_Click);
    }

   WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg,
                                            defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg,
                                            defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg,
                                            defaultArg, defaultArg);

 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB);

 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_Excel);


 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  // WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

   throw;
 }

private void MyButton_Click(CommandBarButton cmdBarbutton, ref bool cancel)
{
   Window m = new Window();
   m.showDialog();  
}
```

Any Suggestion would be great help.

Comment: have you debugged the code? is `MyButton_Click` method executed when you click the button?

Comment: Yes I have debug my code.Debugger goes into that but when I write the code like:-     Window m=new Window(); m.showDialog(); then it shows error.

Comment: this part should be mentioned, it is important to help others reproduce and understand your issue, so add the code and the error message to the question. So you wrote a WPF project, and it opens an Excel file and add a context menu item (button), and when user clicks the button, you want it to open a _new_ WPF Window, right?

Comment: Can you provide me a solution for this ?

Comment: @kennyzx  is their any solution??

Comment: You can again edit this question to "bump" it to the active page.

Comment: @kennyzx can you please suggest any other approach how to acheive this functonality.